# Output frequency of bistable multivibrators

Tags: circuit-analysis

I was wondering if there was a way to determine why the output frequency is half the value of the input frequency based on the schematic. I am currently learning about multivibrators in the Navy and have never seen anything like this in high school physics.

This is what I understand so far about bistable multivibrators: When \$TR_1\$  turns on, the voltage on the collector drops to zero volts, which is the normal common emitter operation when reaching saturation. A negative voltage goes through the resistor to the base of \$TR_2\$. This negative voltage ensures that it does not conduct.We now see +Vcc on the collector of \$TR_2\$ and this is then applied to a resistor to the base of \$TR_1\$. When \$TR_1\$ is on, 0 volts is applied to the cathode of \$D1\$ and +Vcc on the cathode of \$D_2\$, so it is reversed biased.

I was wondering how would you find the period or frequency? And does anyone have a better explanation as to how bistable multivibrators work that includes all the components involved (i.e. diodes, resistors and common emitters).

[image]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/tim17.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation of how the circuit works on [Electronics Tutorials](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/bistable.html).

When a low signal is sent on the trigger line, the pulse is transfered through the capacitors. Whichever side is high (anode of D1 or D2) is pulled low, causing the transistor on that side to turn off. The next trigger pulse reverses which transistor is on.

The reason that the output is half of the input is that it takes 2 trigger pulses to have one pulse on the output.

Answer (score 0):

The transistors are cross-connected so it is only stable with one of the two transistors on, and the other one off. It’s symmetrical- it could be either one on- hence there are two stable states - bi-stable.

If you analyze the circuit assuming a particular one is on, say TR2, and trigger input is high = Vcc, then the left hand 1nF cap will have very little voltage across it, and the right one will be charged to about Vcc.

When the trigger input is suddenly pulled low, it will pull the base of TR2 below ground via D2, turning it off. The right 47k resistor turns TR1 on and the flip-flop is in the other stable state. There is no effect when the trigger is brought high, except the capacitors will begin to charge through the 220k resistors.

So if you put a 100Hz square wave on the trigger, the output switches states on each negative edge and you will see a 50Hz square wave at each collector, 180 degrees out of phase with each other.

The circuit will not work well at high frequencies because of the long time constants, maybe up to a few kHz. There is no lower limit, but if the input falling edge is not sharp enough, the flip-flop will not change state.

You can easily simulate this circuit with LTspice or even the Circuitlab simulator on this site (use the schematic button). Suitable transistors might be 2N3904 and 1N4148 for the diodes. You can then probe the various points and observe the waveforms, all for free..